# cannot import submodules of pyqt4 in macosx

Tags: python, macos, qt

I get the following error when I try to import a submodule of pyqt4 in macosx 10.10 on python 2.7.9:

```
$ python -c "from PyQt4 import QtCore"

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Desktop/lib/python2.7/
site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore

Referenced from: /Users/Desktop/lib/python2.7/
site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so
Reason: image not found
```

I installed pyqt4 from:

https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download

PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.4.tar.gz MacOS/X source

cd PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.4
   python configure-ng.py --destdir=/Users/Desktop/lib/python2.7/site-  packages --sip-incdir=/Users/Desktop/include
   make 
   make install

I have a 64 bit python 2.7.9 and I installed qt using online installer. I did not compile it from the source since that takes a huge amount of memory.

I installed qt using:

qt-unified-mac-x64-2.0.2-2-online.dmg, which is a 64 bit qt.

I noticed that every .so files created by pyqt4 refers to some dylib which does not exist anymore. For instance, QtGui.so refers to libQtGui.dylib,
QtWidgets.so refers to libQtWidgets.dylib, and so forth. Every PyQt4
Qt.so should have a matching libQt.dylib, it appears.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH and/or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and PYTHONPATH are all set correctly, but does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by uninstalling qt5.5 and install qt-opensource-mac-4.8.6-1.dmg. After the installation, just recompile pyqt4 and make install. As below

```
python configure.py -q /usr/bin/qmake-4.8 -d /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ --sip /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sip 

make

make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by making sure that I install sip and pyqt4 for the same architecture.

Specifically, I installed sip with arch flag, which I had not done before.

python configure.py -d /somefolder/lib/python2.7/site-packages -e /somefolder/lib/python2.7/site-packages -p darwin-g++ --arch x86_64

Then make make install.

Later I installed pyqt4

python configure.py --destdir=/somefolder/lib/python2.7/site-packages --use-arch= x86_64
make 
make install

This seems to have solved my problem and I can import pyqt4 submodules without any error.